# Monthly Sales comparison by day

Tags: mysql

I'm using a table to store sales by day and I want a way to get the sales from each day and compare to the same day last month, like this:

I want the number of sales for each day
something like

```
DAYa  | SALESa | DAYb  | SALESb
1     | 3      | 1     | 4
2     | 2      | 2     | 5
```

and so on, but since this month is only 7 days the rest of the days would have 0 sales...
Its one table with all sales.
Something like this.

```
ID | DATE        
1  | 2015-06-01  
2  | 2015-06-02  
3  | 2015-06-02  
4  | 2015-06-02  
30 | 2015-07-01  
40 | 2015-07-05
```

So in the day 2015-06-02 I had 3 sales... and the rest just one sale.

Not sure whats the best way to do that so I can create a graph, should I use 2 queries or is there a way to do with just one ?

Comment: Can you show your schema?  Do you have a table per month?

Comment: Is USER your sales column?  What's the table name?

Comment: Is each row in your second example a sale?  Do we need to count the number of entries per date to get the number of sales per date?  I don't see any correlation between your example table and results.

Comment: yes, each row is a sale, in the day 2015-06-01 I sold one, just one entry, if the day 2015-06-01 had 2 entries it would be 2 sales...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly 1 query but this version will show the current month's sales (in the b columns) next to last month's sales (in the a columns), even if a date had no sales.

```
CREATE TABLE sales_totals AS SELECT `date`, COUNT(*) AS total FROM sales GROUP BY `date`;

SELECT DAY(DATEa) AS DAYa, SALESa, DAY(DATEb) AS DAYb, SALESb
FROM (
    SELECT s1.`date` AS DATEa, s1.total AS SALESa, s2.`date` AS DATEb, s2.total AS SALESb
    FROM sales_totals s1 LEFT JOIN sales_totals s2 ON DATE_ADD(s1.`date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = s2.`date`
    UNION
    SELECT s3.`date` AS DATEa, s3.total AS SALESa, s4.`date` AS DATEb, s4.total AS SALESb
    FROM sales_totals s3 RIGHT JOIN sales_totals s4 ON s3.`date` = DATE_SUB(s4.`date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) x
WHERE YEAR(DATEb) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(DATEb) = MONTH(NOW());

DROP TABLE sales_totals;
```

Comment: Thank you... someone understood what I wanted... I had to change the interval from 1 month to 31 days but everything worked... thank you